# JQuery Find Elements With Data Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to find all elements inside a container that have a certain data attribute set to 1 as well as all elements that don't have this attribute set at all.

The data attribute is as follows:

```
$("#element").data("activate")
```

It can have a value of 1 or 0. If an element doesn't have an "activate" data property set I want to treat it as a 0.

I have the following code at present:

```
$("#content").find("[data-activate='0']").off();
```

However I would also like to do something like this:

```
$("#content").find("all where data-activate NOT exists").off();
```

ie if an element doesn't have the attribute even set.

Comment: Note: there must be unique ID for any element on a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:not`:

```
$('#content :not([data-activate])').off();
```

Or `filter()`:

```
$('#content div').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).attr('data-activate');
}).off();
```

Comment: This is a great answer if your selector identifies the nodes already. If you're using `find` it means you're looking for descendants of `#content`, so use whichever one is appropriate as the situation comes up.

Comment: @Plynx I don't get what you mean - the selector in the first example will find descendants of `#content`

Comment: I caught you between earlier edits, your answer finds descendants now.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#content").find(":not([data-activate])").off();
```

Comment: @Tomalak I think that would apply filter away any `#content` without this attribute, not its descendants. Since `#content` is an id, JQuery takes a shortcut and only returns the first even if you have multiples with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the two selector at once to select the element, separting them (selectors) by comma

1. [:not() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
2. [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

   `$("#content [data-activate='0'], #content :not([data-activate])").off();`

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
$("#content div").map(function {
    $(this).data("activate","1") 
}
```

This will simply add  **data-activate = 1** to all div inside #content whether it is 0 or that attribute does not exist